# Alinear dos ejes "y" a nivel de 0 en C3 js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

estoy intentando alinear los ejes Y respecto al valor 0 , ejemplo: 
http://jsfiddle.net/7kYJu/2587/

temporalmente lo he solucionado poniendo un padding, pero es extremadamente chapuzas y al re-dimensionar el gráfico o al cambiar la data se descoloca (a no ser que se re-calcule el padding de forma dinámica pero nidea de como calcularlo, yo lo he puesto a ojo)

NO me vale la solución de poner el mismo rango en los 2 ejes, ya que la gracia de tener 2 ejes es poner diferentes rangos..

Documentacion oficial: http://c3js.org/reference.html

en esa misma pagina hay ejemplos y el source(menú superior).

Gracias

Comment: Asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32427892/1595451

Answer (score 1):

En esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32438055/1595451) a una [pregunta en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32427892/1595451) para un sólo eje, se indica usar un fragmento que he adaptado de la siguiente forma:

```
// Seleccionar el eje X
    d3.select(chart.element).select('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.axisX).transition()
    // y traducir a la posición de Y = 0
        .attr('transform', "translate(" + 0 + "," + chart.internal.y(0) + ")")
```

En cuando al segundo eje, lo que hay que hacer es agregar como mínimo un valor proporcionalmente equivalente al mínimo del primero. A continuación un ejemplo:

```js
// Calcular el mínimo de la parte negativa del segundo eje Y
var k = (-30 / 400 ) * 50;
var chart = c3.generate({
    data: {
        columns: [
            ['data1', -30, 200, 100, 400, 150, 250],
            ['data2', 50, 20, 10, 40, 15, 25]
        ],
        axes: {
            data1: 'y',
            data2: 'y2'
        }
    },
     axis: {
        y: {
        },
        y2: {
            show: true,
            min: k,
        }
    }
});

// Seleccionar el eje X
d3.select(chart.element).select('.' + c3.chart.internal.fn.CLASS.axisX).transition()
// y traducir a la positición de Y = 0
    .attr('transform', "translate(" + 0 + "," + chart.internal.y(0) + ")")
```

```html
<link href="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/masayuki0812/c3/master/c3.js"></script>
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```